# Update property on old Realm object If not exist on new array

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Hello I have a realm object like bellow. Everytime just before I update realm database I fetch old objects. What I want to do is I want to update removeMe bool to true on all objects which does not exist in new realmObject array. I know this looks like an easy question but I'm searching for the performant way to do it.

I tried to get diff with NSPrecidate function but it says

> Cannot convert value of type 'NSPredicate' to expected argument type
> '(ExampleClass) throws -> Bool'

```
let predicateFilter = NSPredicate(format: "NOT (primarykey IN %@)", oldObjects)
let diff = realmObject.filter(predicateFilter)
```

**EDIT:** To be clear I like to explain what I want to achieve.

Lets say existing realm objects with primary keys of [A, B, C, D] and my new objects have keys of [A, B, D, F, G] then I want to change existing realm objects removeMe property to true on objects with primary key of [C].

Visualialize:

[image]

**P.S:** The reason why I use map is because newArrayFromServer is not a realm object and I'm mapping it to realm object to write it to realm database.

Example Class:

```
class ExampleClass: Object {
@objc dynamic var primaryKey: Int = 0
@objc dynamic var removedDate: Date?
@objc dynamic var removedMe: Bool = false 
override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "primaryKey"
}   
}
```

How I write to Realm Database:

```
let oldObjects = Realm.getObjects(ExampleClass.self)
let realmObject = newArrayFromServer.map { (user) -> ExampleClass in
    let realmUser = ExampleClass(user: user)
    return realmUser
}
let realm = try! Realm()
try! realm.write {
    realm.add(realmObject, update: .modified)
}
```

I found a solution which is not that performant. Code below run for loop on old data and check if there is any record which doesn't exist on new response and change the boolean

```
let realm = try! Realm()
let oldRecords = RealmHelper.getObjects(t: ExampleClass.self)
let newFetchedRecords = backendResponse.map { (newRecord) -> ExampleClass in
    let realmUser = ExampleClass(user: newRecord)
    return realmUser
}
oldRecords.forEach { (oldRecord) in
    try! realm.write({
        if newFetchedRecords.contains(oldRecord) == false {
            oldRecord.removedMe = true
        } else {
            oldRecord.removedMe = false
        }
    })
}
try! realm.write({
    realm.add(newFetchedRecords, update: .modified)
})
```

Comment: A few things. First the question is very unclear - what are you attempting to do? The included code is disjointed and the vars are unrelated to each other. Second thing is that the ExampleClass `primaryKey` function appears to be outside the class - is that intentional? Last thing is that once Realm object is removed from a results, it's no longer is a Realm object. e.g. this `newArrayFromServer.map { (user) -> ExampleClass` takes all of those objects and makes them non-managed which is probably not what you want. Please update the question.

Comment: Hello I add more description to be more clear. The reason why I use map is because newArrayFromServer is not a realm object and I'm mapping it to realm object to write it to realm database.

Comment: It's not really clear how and existing realm object would be 'contained' in a a set of newly created objects? They will never be 'equal' because they are different objects. You could test to see if they contain the same string for example or some other property but even if you implemented the equatable protocol, Realm objects have unique primary keys so again, the object won't be equal. I kind of get what you're attempting but can you clarify what would make a Realm oldObject be equal to a newObject since their primaryKeys must be unique?

Comment: Yes objects have unique primary keys. So If we assume two objects are equal, they should have same private key.

Comment: Your question states *I call my backend and fetch 8 object which are all exactly same (has same private key) on my offline realm database* I assume you mean *primary* key, not *private* so that's not possible - primary keys cannot be *exactly the same* as they must be unique. See the documentation on [Primary Keys](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/ios/objects#primary-key) which states **the primary key property... that is unique among objects of the same type in a realm** and also from the docs **Declaring a primary key... enforces uniqueness for each value**

Comment: The question still need further clarification as well; *The reason why I use map is because newArrayFromServer is not a realm object* which is fine. However, since those objects do not have primary keys to compare to the realm objects that DO have primary keys, how do you know if the new object already exists or not. e.g. what's the test? Which property or value do you want to use to see if the object already exists?

Comment: @Jay Yes sorry. I meant primary key, I wrote it wrongly. I changed it now. For your second comment, those objects also have primary keys so when I'm creating realm objects, It is being creating with same primary key. So for example an object with primary key "1"  and name "Emre" is in my offline database, when I fetch same data from backend It also returns "1" as primary key and I'm creating realm object with primary key "1" so I can check if this object is in offline database already.

Comment: Ok - that's not well outlined in the question so I would update it. I think the approach should be different. What you seem to be after is a NOT IN query. In other words if your *existing* realm objects with primary keys of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] and your *new* objects have keys of [1, 3, 5] then you want to change *existing* realm objects removeMe property to true on objects with primary key of [2, 4]. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes thats correct. I'll edit my question like this.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is something like this: (Assuming your primary key is String type)

```
let realm = try! Realm()
let oldKeySet = Set(Realm.getObjects(ExampleClass.self).map {$0.primaryKey})
let newKeySet = Set(backendResponse.map { (newRecord) -> String in
    let realmUser = ExampleClass(user: newRecord)
    return realmUser.primaryKey
})
let removedKeySet = oldKeySet.subtracting(newKeySet)
try! realm.write({
    removedKeySet.forEach {
        let object = realm.object(ofType:ExampleClass.self, forPrimaryKey: $0)
        object.removedMe = true
    }
})
```

Comment: While this answer works, there's no need for `Set` as primaryKeys are unique (primary keys MUST be unique). Also creating ExampleClass objects doesn't have a purpose here - they go out of scope within the map closure so they are not needed. It would be faster and less code to just iterate over the backendResponse array and grab the primaryKeys from that.

Comment: You seems not to know that the Set is used for the subtract operation. For the newKeySet part, I agree with your last sentence. I just copied the code from the question and the asker would found it himself. As it was to clear to say.

Comment: lol. Not a good assumption. I was simply stating it wasn't necessary. This one line will produce the desired results `let usersPrimaryKeysToUpdate = existingUserArray.filter { !newUserArray.contains($0) }` given there's an array of primaryKeys. Your answer definitely works either way.

Comment: I agree your code is shorter than mine. And the filter part is brilliant. It did need taking some time of thinking and it was something that never came to my mind before and inspired me. Basically, the two answers are the same algorithm, but in different approacher. Yours was deeper than mine. I also got learnings from your answer. So thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Let me re-state the question

> What is a query that will return realm objects that are NOT in a list?

For example:

> Given existing realm objects with primary keys of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] and
> new objects with keys of [1, 3, 5], return the existing objects that
> are not in the new objects group; the result would be [2, 4]

Fortunately, it can be done with one line of code. Given we have an String array of newPrimaryKeys:

```
let examplesToUpdate = realm.objects(ExampleClass.self).filter("!(primaryKey IN %@)", newPrimaryKeys)
```

This reads: get all existing ExampleClass objects where their primaryKey is not in the newPrimaryKey array.

Then to update all of the examplesToUpdate removeMe property to true, it's a single line of code

```
examplesToUpdate.setValue(true, forKey: "removedMe")
```